# Rails 5: reverse serializer to create or update local record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization, ruby-on-rails-5

Is a (reverse) serializer the correct way to create a record in a Rails app from JSON that doesn't necessary match keys? Or is there another approach that's more standard/works better?

This class processes an internal record to be understood by an external service.

```
class LeadOutSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attribute :external_id, key: 'Id'
  attribute :first_name, key: 'FirstName'
  attribute :last_name, key: 'LastName'
  attribute :name, key: 'Name'
  attribute :zip, key: 'PostalCode'
  ...
end
```

I want to make a `LeadInSerializer` or something like that to invoke when the external service posts data to this application. What's the best approach there?

Comment: The correct way really depends on your use case. Can you publish an API and require that external services use it? If so then its the best option.

Comment: That's probably outside the scope of this task. I really would like the simplest idea that would reverse the translation in the serializer above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deserialization, like you describe, isn't something that ActiveModelSerializers supports (it has experimental support for deserializing JsonAPI payloads, but you aren't using that schema). The reason is simply that many custom serializers aren't reversible: you can use relations, custom methods, combine properties, encode values, etc, etc; all of which aren't possible for a library to know how you want to deserialize.

So, other than some very clever metaprogramming to automatically generate a deserializer (which might be possible for trivial attribute-mapping serializers, like the one you posted), your only option is to write a deserializer by hand.

My suggestion would be to load in your JSON document as a hash, and then use a hash transform tool (like https://github.com/joshkrueger/htransform) to remap the keys to the attributes of your model, and then apply that hash as an update to your model.

Comment: That's probably the best solution for this issue. Thanks.